# KnpSnappyBundle dont asset images

Tags: symfony, wkhtmltopdf

I use in controler:

```
 $html = $this->renderView('RaportBundle:pdf:magazinesbarcode.html.twig', array(
            'magazines'  => $magazines
        ));

        return new Response(
            $this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->getOutputFromHtml($html,
                array('images'=> true,'enable-external-links' => true)
            ),
            200,
            array(
                'images' =>true,
                'Content-Type'          => 'application/pdf',
                'Content-Disposition'   => 'attachment; filename="file.pdf"'
            )
        );
```

Normal documentation example.
HTML generate well, with my absolute img path

```
<img src="{{ asset('uploads/barcode/2.jpg', absolute=true) }}" />
```

But in pdf image didn't displayed.
If i saved generated html and use wkhtmltopdf on this file from console image saves well in pdf.
So problem is in Snappy budle.
Windows 8.1 x64.
Whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should use absolute local path to an image:

```
<img src="{{ rootDir ~ '/web' ~ asset('uploads/barcode/2.jpg') }}">
```

where `rootDir` is passed to the template:

```
$html = $this->renderView('RaportBundle:pdf:magazinesbarcode.html.twig', array(
            'magazines'  => $magazines,
            'rootDir' => $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir().'/..'
        ));
```

Comment: As of Symfony 2.5  you can also do this for absolute paths: `<img src="{{ asset('uploads/barcode/2.jpg', absolute=true) }}" />`

Comment: So i use absolute path, read my problem. Symfony 2.6.3.Absolute path generated well but dont work. @dmnptr solution, didnt work too.

Comment: My solution works well for me, with Symfony 2.3. Check file permissions, just to make sure it is not the cause.